# Angular UI Router - pass some params state in route, and some not?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to be able to pass some state params that will show up in the route, and some that won't.

It would be nice to be able to do this:

```
.state('widgetadmin.widgets.widget', {
            url: '/widget/{widgetId}/{friendlyName}',
            views: {
                "sub@widgetadmin": {
                    controller: 'WidgetAdminController as vm',
                    templateUrl: 'widgetadmin/widgets/widget.tpl.html',
                    params: { widgetHref: null }
                }
            },
            data:{ pageTitle: 'Edit Widget' }
        }
```

Then pass it like this:

```
$state.go('widgetadmin.widgets.widget',
            {widgetId: widget.id, friendlyName: slug, widgetHref: widget._links.self.href},
            {reload: true});
```

But when I try to access it, it's undefined:

```
var something = $stateParams.widgetHref;
```

How can I pass some state params in route, and some not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to put the params in a different place:

```
.state('widgetadmin.widgets.widget', {
        url: '/widget/{widgetId}/{friendlyName}',
        views: {
            "sub@widgetadmin": {
                controller: 'WidgetAdminController as vm',
                templateUrl: 'widgetadmin/widgets/widget.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data:{ pageTitle: 'Edit Widget' },
        params: { widgetHref: null }
    }
```